# Cross-compiling Flex/Flash to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache-flex, flash, cross-compiling

Are there any options for compiling Flex/Flash projects into Javascript/JQuery?  I seem to remember this feature possibly being part of Adobe's latest dev tools?

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://www.jangaroo.net

Answer (score 1):

Adobe is now working on Falcon(JS).
that would crosscompile Flex projects to JS.

http://blogs.adobe.com/bparadie/2011/11/19/what-is-falconjs/

Comment: Adobe will contribute FalconJS, but it's far from being a released product. Adobe had one developer working on FalconJS, just as a proof of concept. The Falcon compiler has been contributed to the Apache Flex project, and FalconJS should be contributed until the end of the year.  
If there's enough interest in the Flex community, the proof-of-concept might be turned into something useful.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe has contributed the FalconJS proof-of-concept or prototype source code to Apache Flex. This is not a finished product, but some simple applications can be cross-compiled to JavaScript. The source code can be check out here:

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/flex/falcon/trunk/compiler.js/

FalconJS depends on the Falcon compiler, which has been contributed to the Apache Flex project as well, here is the wiki page with the build instructions for Falcon:

https://cwiki.apache.org/FLEX/falcon-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

OpenLaszlo is an open-source development platform that can compile applications into either a Flash SWF or HTML5/DHTML (ie: HTML+JavaScrtipt). The syntax of the language consists of XML mixed with ActionScript/JavaScript:

http://www.openlaszlo.org/

Note:

ActionScript and JavaScript are both implementations of the ECMAScript language (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) and thus are nearly identical. Anyone familiar with programming in ActionScript or JavaScript should feel right at home with OpenLaszlo script.